# Is there a way to allow entering a value in a node's field if inserting a new node, but make the field disabled if updating that same node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have a standard text field in my Content Type. If the user with role "Standard User" is adding a new node then they should be able to set the Status field text value. However, if the node is already created and they are editing/updating that same node, it should be grayed-out (disabled). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Other than do it with Form API and hook_form_alter?

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];

  if ($form_id == "my_content_type_node_form") {

    global $user;

    if (isset($user)) {

      $user_has_standard_user_role = FALSE;

      // Get role information about the user.
      $user_roles = array();
      foreach ($user->roles as $key => $role) {
        $user_roles[$key] = $role;
      }

      foreach ($user_roles as $key => $user_role) {
        if ($user_role == "Standard User") {
          $user_has_standard_user_role = TRUE;
        }
      } // end iterate through user roles

      if ($user_has_standard_user_role) {

        // If this is a new node, let the user edit the field.
        if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
          $form['field_status_field']['und']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
        }

        // If this is not a new node, then disable the field.
        else {
          $form['field_status_field']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
        }
      } // end if user has Standard User role.

      // User is not Standard User, so disable the field.
      else { 
        $form['field_status_field']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
      }
    } // end if user is set
  } // end if correct form ID
 } // end function
```